# ggplot flip and transform coordinate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to transform the coordinate (not the scale/values) so that the y variable (flipped to x) is better spaced. I thought it would be `coord_trans(y="log10")` or `coord_trans(y="log2")` or something, but this does not seem to work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dat <- structure(list(median=c(2893, 0, 907.5, 1315, 0, 84, 98, 953, 
                               0, 0, 1349, 17.5, 48.5, 7, 28, 18, 14, 37.5, 0, 383, 220.5, 49, 
                               86.5, 816.5, 38, 41, 38, 1302, 14, 0, 1304, 754, 424.5, 0, 35.5, 
                               28, 32, 0, 39), 
                      name = c("name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", 
                               "name 5", "name 6", "name 7", "name 8", "name 9", "name 10", 
                               "name 11", "name 12", "name 13", "name 14", "name 15", "name 16", 
                               "name 17", "name 18", "name 19", "name 20", "name 21", "name 22", 
                               "name 23", "name 24", "name 25", "name 26", "name 27", "name 28", 
                               "name 29", "name 30", "name 31", "name 32", "name 33", "name 34", 
                               "name 35", "name 36", "name 37", "name 38", "name 39")), 
                 .Names = c("median", "name"), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = "data.frame")


dat = transform(dat, name = reorder(name, median))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(y=median, x=name)) +
  #coord_trans(y="log10") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

I do NOT want to rescale the values:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(y=median, x=name)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: `coord_flip(...)` and `coord_trans(...)` are both `coord_*` functions, so they can't be "stacked" - they override each other. The way you are using it, `coord_flip(...)` overrides `coord_trans(...)`, which is why you see no effect. If you reverse the lines of code, you get log10 transformation, but no flipping. Why do you **not** want to rescale - it accomplishes the same thing??

Comment: Thanks, @jlhoward. I forgot that about `coord_` functions. I only want to change the spacing, not the labels. See [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/#axis-transformations-log-sqrt-etc) and look at log2 scaling vs log2 transformation. The first and third images show the axis on the original scale.

Comment: So you want the labels to be `1000, 2000, 3000` but spaced on a log10 scale? Try adding `breaks=c(1000,2000,3000)` to the call to `scale_y_log10(...)`

Comment: Great! This works. I've added more breaks at the lower end to fit my case, but the idea is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so now that I understand your question, here's the answer in hopes it will help others.

First, the `coord_*` functions cannot be stacked - they override each other. So tthe way you are using it, `coord_flip(...)` overrides `coord_trans(...)` and you don't see any transformations.

To get log10 spacing with tick labels based on the linear spacing, with flipped coordinates, you can use the `breaks=...` argument to `scale_*`, as in:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(y=median, x=name)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks=1000*(1:3)) +   # note use of breaks=...
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: How would you handle the case where the scale is "logit"? This approach, unfortunately does not work.