# Flip coords for ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, transform, boxplot

I would like to flip the coords for a ggplot2 boxplot where I also do a coordinate transformation.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(group = factor(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,6))),
                 vals   = c(c(0.1,2.25,1000), c(0.11,0.21,0.21,4.55,5.06,29.48)))


   ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + geom_boxplot() 
   ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + geom_boxplot()  + coord_trans(y="log10")
```

If I just add now "+ coord_flip()", the log scaling of the axis is lost..

```
 ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + geom_boxplot()  + coord_trans(y="log10") + coord_flip()
```

Any way to achieve flipping of coords?

Thanks for any comments!

Best,
Stefanie

Comment: Did you read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26185278/1305688)?

Comment: @Eric Fail. Oops. I didn't see this comment. You suggested first. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have seen this post. However, it does not solve my problem. See my comment to the answer below. Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe there is workaround. You can flip your plot using `viewport()`. EDIT: using package `cowplot`, you can switch the y axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + geom_boxplot()  + coord_trans(y="log10") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

pp <- ggdraw(switch_axis_position(p, axis = 'y'))

grid.newpage()
print(pp, vp = viewport(angle = -90, width = 0.7, height = 0.8))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have already considered this option..
However, I somehow don't like the x-axis is on top of the graph, rather than - as usual - on the bottom....

Comment: that's cool, I was not aware of 'switch_axis_position'. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just use `scale_y_log10`:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + 
 geom_boxplot() + 
 coord_flip() + 
 scale_y_log10()
```

Then just adjust as needed.

Comment: In this case, I do a different transformation. The data is transformed before computing the summary statistics for the boxplot. Check out how the boxplot changes: 
ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + geom_boxplot()  + coord_trans(y="log10")   versus 

ggplot(dat,aes(group,vals)) + geom_boxplot()  + scale_y_log10()

So, I definitely just want to apply coordinate transformation, not scale transformation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are the same. It is just a difference between the data or the scale being transformed.

Comment: Have you checked the boxplots? In this case it makes a difference if you calculate the median before or after doing the log10 transformation.

Comment: This alters the data, not just the presentation. Quantiles will be presented, but NOT the whiskers. So this is wrong approach.