# ggplot boxplot - length of whiskers with logarithmic axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to create a horizontal boxplot with logarithmic axis using ggplot2. But, the length of whiskers are wrong.

A minimal reproducible example:

Some data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(1234)
my.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000,150,50), b = rnorm(1000,500,150))
my.df$a[which(my.df$a < 5)] <- 5
my.df$b[which(my.df$b < 5)] <- 5
```

If I plot this using base R `boxplot()`, everything is fine

```
boxplot(my.df, log="x", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

But with ggplot,

```
my.df.long <- melt(my.df, value.name = "vals")
ggplot(my.df.long, aes(x=variable, y=vals)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000), limits=c(5,1000)) +
  theme_bw() + coord_flip()
```

I get this plot, in which the whiskers are the wrong length (see for example how there are many additional outliers below the whiskers and none above).

[image]

Note that, without log axes, ggplot has the whiskers the correct length

```
ggplot(my.df.long, aes(x=variable, y=vals)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() + coord_flip()
```

[image]

How do I produce a horizontal logarithmic boxplot using ggplot with the correct length whiskers? Preferably with the whiskers extending to 1.5 times the IQR.

**N.B.** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3388026/2761575). It is possible to use `coord_trans(y = "log10")` instead of `scale_y_log10`, which will cause the stats to be calculated *before* transforming the data. *However*, `coord_trans` cannot be used in combination with `coord_flip`. So this does not solve the issue of creating horizontal boxplots with a log axis.

Comment: Look at `?geom_boxplot`. `ggplot` and `boxplot` use different methods of calculating the "hinges"

Comment: @MikeyMike Thanks - that is good to know.  But even so, the 2 versions of ggplot - with and without log axis - place the hinges at different positions

Comment: Could it be a transforming the scales vs transforming the coordinate system issue?  Using `scale_x_log10` is the same as using `log(vals)` as the y variable.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954247/flip-coords-for-ggplot2-boxplot) looks relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `scale_y_log10` transforms the data before calculating the stats. This does not matter for the median and percentile points, because e.g. `10^log10(median)` is still the median value, which will be plotted in the correct location. But it *does* matter for the whiskers which are calculated using `1.5 * IQR`, because `10^(1.5 * IQR(log10(x))` is not equal to `1.5 * IQR(x)`. So the calculation fails for the whiskers.

This error becomes evident if we compare

```
boxplot.stats(my.df$b)$stats
# [1] 117.4978 407.3983 502.0460 601.2937 873.0992
10^boxplot.stats(log10(my.df$b))$stats
# [1] 231.1603 407.3983 502.0459 601.2935 975.1906
```

In which we see that the median and percentile ppoints are identical, but the whisker ends (1st and last elements of the stats vector) differ

[This detailed and useful answer by @eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38755237/2761575), shows how to calculate the stats yourself and force ggplot to use these user-defined stats rather than its internal (and incorrect) algorithm.  Using this approach, it becomes relatively simple to calculate the correct statistics and use these instead.

```
# Function to use boxplot.stats to set the box-and-whisker locations  
mybxp = function(x) {
  bxp = log10(boxplot.stats(10^x)[["stats"]])
  names(bxp) = c("ymin","lower", "middle","upper","ymax")
  return(bxp)
}  

# Function to use boxplot.stats for the outliers
myout = function(x) {
  data.frame(y=log10(boxplot.stats(10^x)[["out"]]))
}

ggplot(my.df.long, aes(x=variable, y=vals)) + theme_bw() + coord_flip() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000), limits=c(5,1000)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mybxp, geom="boxplot") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=myout, geom="point")
```

Which produces the correct plot

[image]

**A note on using `coord_trans` as an alternative approach:**

Using `coord_trans(y = "log10")` instead of `scale_y_log10`, causes the stats to be calculated (correctly) on the untransformed data. *However*, `coord_trans` cannot be used in combination with `coord_flip`. So, this does not solve the issue of creating horizontal boxplots with a log axis. The suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954247/flip-coords-for-ggplot2-boxplot/34962121#34962121) to use `ggdraw(switch_axis_position())` from the cowplot package to flip the axes after using `coord_trans` did not work, but throws an error (cowplot v0.4.0 with ggplot2 v2.1.0)

> Error in Ops.unit(gyl$x, grid::unit(0.5, "npc")) :    both operands
>   must be units
>
> In addition: Warning message: `axis.ticks.margin` is
>   deprecated. Please set `margin` property  of `axis.text` instead

Comment: In addition to the grid.draw option, check out package ggstance for horizontal geoms.

Answer (score 4):

You can have `ggplot` use `boxplot.stats` (the same function used by base `boxplot`) to set the y-values for the box-and-whiskers and the outliers. For example:

```
# Function to use boxplot.stats to set the box-and-whisker locations  
mybxp = function(x) {
  bxp = boxplot.stats(x)[["stats"]]
  names(bxp) = c("ymin","lower", "middle","upper","ymax")
  return(bxp)
}  

# Function to use boxplot.stats for the outliers
myout = function(x) {
  data.frame(y=boxplot.stats(x)[["out"]])
}
```

Now we use those functions in `stat_summary` to draw the boxplot, as in the example below:

```
ggplot(my.df.long, aes(x=variable, y=vals)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mybxp, geom="boxplot") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=myout, geom="point") +
  theme_bw() + coord_flip()
```

Now for the log transformation issue: The plots below show, respectively, no coordinate transformation, `scale_y_log10`, and `coord_trans(y="log10")`. In addition, I've used `geom_hline` to add dotted lines at each of the box-and-whisker values and I've added text to show the actual values. To reduce clutter, I've removed the outlier points, and I've faded out the boxplots a bit so that the other components will show up better.

```
# Set up common plot elements
p = ggplot(my.df.long, aes(x=variable, y=vals)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mybxp(my.df$a), colour="red", lty="11", size=0.3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mybxp(my.df$b), colour="blue", lty="11", size=0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mybxp, geom="boxplot", colour="#000000A0", fatten=0.5) +
  #stat_summary(fun.data=myout, geom="point") +
  theme_bw() + coord_flip()

br = c(5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000)

## Create plots

# Without log transformation
p1 = p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=br, limits=c(5,1000)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mybxp, aes(label=round(..y..)), geom="text", size=3, colour="red") +
  ggtitle("No Transformation")

# With scale_y_log10
p2 = p + scale_y_log10(breaks=br, limits=c(5,1000)) + ggtitle("scale_y_log10") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mybxp, aes(label=round(..y..,2)), geom="text", size=3, colour="red") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mybxp, aes(label=round(10^(..y..))), geom="text", size=3, 
               colour="blue", position=position_nudge(x=0.3)) 

# With coord_trans
p3 = p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=br, limits=c(5,1000)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mybxp, aes(label=round(..y..)), geom="text", size=3, colour="red") +
  coord_trans(y="log10") + ggtitle("coord_trans(y='log 10')")
```

The three plots are shown below. Note that the last plot, using `coord_trans` is not flipped, because `coord_trans` overrides `coord_flip`. You can probably use something like the code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34962121/496488) to flip the plot, but I haven't done that here.

The first plot, with no transformations, shows the correct values.

The third plot, using `coord_trans` also has everything in the correct locations. Note that `coord_trans` is actually changing the y-coordinate system of the plot without changing the values of the plotted points. It's the space itself that's been "distorted" to a log scale.

Now, note that in the second plot, using `scale_y_log10`, the boxes are in the correct locations but the ends of the whiskers are in the wrong locations. On the other hand, comparison with the other two plots shows that the location of all the `geom_hline`s is correct. Also note that, unlike `coord_trans`, `scale_y_log10` takes the log of the points themselves and just relabels the y-axis breaks with the unlogged values, while leaving the "space" in the which the points are plotted unchanged. You can see this by looking at the values in red text. The values in blue text are the unlogged values.

See [@dww's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757310/496488) for an explanation of why `scale_y_log10` results only in the whisker ends being transformed incorrectly, while the box values are plotted in the right place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eipi10, this was a really great help. Unfortunately, I could not find a way turn a `coord_trans` plot horizontal, successfully. But I was able to adapt your stats functions to the task, and to explain the 'mystery' of why the whisker stats are calculated wrong by ggplot.  See my answer below.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure that out. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest answer if you don't need to make the boxplots horizontal is to transform the coordinate system in stead of changing the scale, using `coord_trans(y = "log10")` in stead of `scale_y_log10()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  As already explained in my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757310/2761575): `coord_trans` can't be used in combination with `coord_flip` on horizontal boxplots.