# Set up a boxplot with its specific range limits, is it possible?

Tags: r, boxplot

I don't know if it is possible in R but I would like to set up my own boxplot with specific whiskers and box limits.

The normal boxplots show the min value, 1st quartile, 3rd quartile and max value (plus outliers, if any). I would like to substitute the 1st quartile to 5% (5th percentile) and 3rd quartile to 95% (95th percentile) by keeping the whiskers extremes as min and max values. So, the box should now contains the 90% of my data (90 percentiles).

Is there any way to do it?

I know about the existence of the function `range` in `boxplot` but I don't think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Look at the `?bxp` function. It will draw the boxes with whatever statistics you pass it. For a more complete example, you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks, I will. If I will find the answer on my own I will post it.

Comment: Or if you want to use ggplot, you can see how to use your own stats here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38757310/2761575