# How can I flip and then zoom in on a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes("", price)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

[image: Diamond Prices]

After flipping the box plot, how can I zoom in to `c(0,7000)` on price (which is the new x-axis)?

I feel like it has something to do with `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 7000))`, **but this doesn't seem to work in conjunction with** `coord_flip()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes("", price)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip(ylim=c(0, 7000))
```

Just combine the `ylim` command as argument in `coord_flip()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_y_continuous()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes("", price)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 7000))
```

Remember that coord_flip() just rotates the plot, hence you call scale_ on the *y* axis, which is what you specify `price` as. I usually like to call it last for that reason: to help limit confusion over which axis is which!

Comment: That outputs a different boxplot, though. The upper hinge, e.g., is now under 5,000.

Comment: @JanVanhove good catch. See [this question & answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753628/ggplot-boxplot-length-of-whiskers-with-logarithmic-axis) for detail on why the hinges change and how to avoid it

Comment: `scale_*` does not zoom in on a plot, only a `ylim` or `xlim` argument to `coord_*` does. For more, see this [post](http://rpubs.com/jhofman/zoom_ggplot2).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to manually compute the boxplot statistics and plot these.

```
# Compute summary statistics with max (y100) set to cutoff (7000)
df <- data.frame(x = 1,
             y0 = min(diamonds$price),
             y25 = quantile(diamonds$price, 0.25),
             y50 = median(diamonds$price),
             y75 = quantile(diamonds$price, 0.75),
             y100 = 7000
             )

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = y0, lower = y25, middle = y50, upper = y75, ymax = y100),
          stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: This may give the desired solution (I'm not sure exactly what the asker is after), but the resulting visualisation will be a slight misrepresentation of the data as some of the data has been artificially "hidden" and the displayed statistics (e.g. median, IQR) are not those of the data being shown, but of some other data not all of which is displayed in the visualisation.

Comment: I agree. Log-transforming the x-axis may be a better solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: Or this which I saw today from Thomas Pedersen: https://twitter.com/thomasp85/status/779289579232821248

Yet to be release but worth watching!

Comment: Note that log transforming the data on a fliiped boxplot introduces its own complications with ggplot calculating the stats incorrectly.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753628/ggplot-boxplot-length-of-whiskers-with-logarithmic-axis

Comment: Also, I should point out that the stats you use here are incorrect for a boxplot (whiskers do not extend to max and min).  You should use `boxplot.stats()` to calculate stats and outliers.