# coord_flip() and a horizontal log10 scale using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I need to stack band into TWh for each ISO3 using log10 scale in TWh.

I have generated the following lines without the log scale but testing it.

Here the code

```
> head(exx)
  ISO3   band        ET    TWh
  <fct> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AFG       1 37418724. 37.4  
2 AFG       2   890119.  0.890
3 AFG       3   554229.  0.554
4 AFG       4   516820.  0.517
5 AFG       5  5773072.  5.77 
6 AFG       6   249360.  0.249

exx %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(ISO3, TWh, sum), y = TWh, fill = as.factor(band))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 3, title = "band")) +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0),
    legend.position = c(0.995, 0.001),
    text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color="black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7, color="black"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line( size=.1, color="grey", linetype = 2 )) +
  #here i tested
  #scale_y_continuous(trans=log10_trans())+
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_npg()
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yCjqolMnwdKl3GdoHL6iWNXsd6yFais5?usp=sharing) the data

Here the expected figure (here I need to add the log scale)
[image]

This is what I got when testing the log scale. Also, how can interpret this fig?
[image]

Any help is very well appreciated.
I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183958/ggplot-flip-and-transform-coordinate) but does not work.

**# Modified attempt**

I have multiplied by 1000000 and then applied the following:

```
scale_y_continuous(trans=log10_trans(), 
                 #breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x))+#, 
                 labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x)))+
```

and get this

[image]

I would like now to get the original labels in the breaks.

Comment: Could you provide your data using `dput(df)` rather than giving a link to the data?

Comment: Bar charts expect the y-axis to start from 0, but since log of number < 1 are negative and the log(0) is -Inf, using a log scale does not make sense for this data.  You could add 1 to every value and then perform the log transformation, this "standardize" the value could provide a valid comparison from the large countries to the small ones, with a shifted baseline.

Comment: @NelsonGon I tried already but it is too long, that's why I believed it is better to have the link and call a head() at the beginning.

Comment: @Dave2e many thanks for your explanation. That's totally make sense. I'll try the recommendation.

Comment: You can also try a aqrt scale

Comment: I have added scale_y_continuous(trans=log10_trans(), 
                     breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x))+
                     labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x)))+, but I dont know how to get original results in the labels. Please see the modified result/code.

Comment: Please see my last attempt and let me know if you have any contribution.